# Premature end of file error when building DOM document object

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

When I create the Document object I encounter a premature end of file error. This code was working a few days ago and I'm unsure of what is causing it to throw an error now.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));
Document doc = builder.parse(is);
```

> [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.

Here is the response xml I am receiving. It looks perfectly fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetBatchFilesResponse xmlns="http://....">
            <GetBatchFilesResult>
                <BatchFile>
                    <Uri>someURI</Uri>
                    <ID>2025961</ID>
                    <FQName>someFileName</FQName>
                </BatchFile>
            </GetBatchFilesResult>
        </GetBatchFilesResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did the XML content change since then? Because the error message hints that it has...

Comment: problem is more likely to be in what is in your `response` variable.

Comment: I'ved added my xml response in to the question for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates that you have a **badly formed** `XML` response. Usually this message pops up when there is an opening tag with no matching end tag in the `XML`. I think you'll also get this on an **empty** response.

Comment: It's not an empty XML response though. There is also no missing tags in the response

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new line to the xml , some parsers require it.

Answer (score -3):

I reverted back to some old code that was in my local history and it started to work. I made some minor changes with some of the logic in my code and for some reason, those small changes affected the way it handled the response.

Comment: What did you change specifically?